# Why does my script get HTML back from a GET request instead of an image for a certain URL/domain?

Tags: vba, vba7

I have a script and it should download an image and write it to a file on my harddrive.
It works for all domains I have tested so far but for this specific one, I only get HTML written into my files and no image.

My Script:

```
Sub DownloadAndSaveFile(downloadUrl As String, fileFormat As String, outputPath As String, outputName As String)
    Dim WinHttpReq As Object
    Set WinHttpReq = CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
    WinHttpReq.Open "GET", downloadUrl, False
    WinHttpReq.send
    
    If WinHttpReq.Status = 200 Then
        Set oStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
        oStream.Open
        oStream.Type = 1
        oStream.Write WinHttpReq.responseBody
        oStream.SaveToFile outputPath + outputName + fileFormat, 2 ' 1 = no overwrite, 2 = overwrite
        oStream.Close
    End If

End Sub
```

This is one of the URLs that fails: https://media.lunardistribution.com/images/covers/large/1122AH225.jpg

However, if I try the GET request via Postman, I get the image like it should be (see image below)

How can I fix this so the actual image gets saved?

[image]

Comment: Use "&" instead of "+"?  This URL works for me.  Do `debug.print "X" & downloadUrl & "X"` and `debug.print "X" & outputPath & outputName & fileFormat & "X"` and check.

Comment: What does it say in the HTML you get back?  That might be useful here.

Comment: It was a typo from me. The debug print from @dcromley helped me find the problem